# how to solve route issue in Rails 4 with omniauth authentication?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

i am using self omniauth to for authentication with Rails 4

but it giving error at first stage

[image]

i did same as omniauth documentation.

Gemfile:

```
gem "omniauth", "= 1.1.4"

gem 'omniauth-google'

gem 'omniauth-twitter'
```

i also created initialization file.

any solution ?

Comment: What have you got in your routes file for callback?

Comment: get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'auths#create'

Comment: is `auths` your controller that has an action `create`?

Comment: yes.. auths have action 'create'

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm stuck with the same problem